# Elasticsearch: hyphen in PrefixQuery on Keyword-analyzed field

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a situation where I'm putting metadata for invoices into an Elasticsearch 1.5.2 index, running on Ubuntu Linux 15.04 with Oracle JDK 8u45. One of the fields is poNumber, which often has values that look like "123-R45678" or "123-4Q5678". I'm trying to use a PrefixQuery (via the query parser) to search for values that start with a prefix, such as "123-4*" or "123-R*". The closest I have come to success is using the Keyword analyzer on the poNumber field, and using the same Keyword analyzer when searching, with a URL that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=invoices.poNumber:123-4Q*&analyzer=keyword&analyze_wildcard=true&explain=true
```

This returns no results, despite "123-4Q5678" being in the index. However, when I search for "123-4*", I do get results and it matches on "123-4Q5678":

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=invoices.poNumber:123-4*&analyzer=keyword&analyze_wildcard=true&explain=true
```

The Keyword analyzer should not be doing anything to break apart the string. I've even tested this at the _analyze endpoint. Prefix queries looking for values without hyphens seem to work fine. Why does adding the "Q" character cause this query to not return results? This also happens if the letter is right after the hyphen.

Also, when a hyphen is present, it doesn't return results even when the entire string value is the "prefix" of the PrefixQuery. However, it does return results in an exact match query. (see below) If a hyphen is not present in the value or query, searching for the exact value as the prefix *does* return the matching document.

Here's some other results of testing:

```
value        search term    success
123-4Q5678   123*           yes
123-4Q5678   123-*          yes
123-4Q5678   123-4*         yes
123-4Q5678   123-4Q*        no
123-4Q5678   123-4Q5*       no
123-4Q5678   123-4Q5678*    no
123-4Q5678   123-4Q5678     yes
123-R45678   123*           yes
123-R45678   123-*          yes
123-R45678   123-R*         no
123-R45678   123-R4*        no
123-R45678   123-R45678*    no
123-R45678   123-R45678     yes
r4q567       R*             yes
r4q567       R4*            yes
r4q567       R4Q*           yes
r4q567       R4Q567*        yes
r4q567       R4Q567         yes
```

Comment: Have you tried using [ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) and the query DSL instead of prefix queries? I wrote a blog post about ngrams here: http://blog.qbox.io/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch. If it would be helpful I can show you a simple example using the data you posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `q=...` syntax, as well.
`q=...` [refers to `query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) actually, but is a shorter version.

And `query_string` is a bit confusing, because it has some defaults that one needs to be aware of to explain some situations.

This is the case with your attempts: there is a setting called `lowercase_expanded_terms` which is `true` by default. What this does is to lowercase the input string. So, when you are searching for `123-4Q*` you are, in fact, searching for `123-4q*` (lowercased). But, in your index with `keyword` analyzed you have upper-case **Q** which will never match.

Your query will work with the following command:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=invoices.poNumber:123-4Q*&analyzer=keyword&lowercase_expanded_terms=false
```

And if you're wondering why `123-4Q5678` matches despite being upper-cased, is because `lowercase_expanded_terms` applies in certain conditions, wildcard being one of them:

> Whether terms of wildcard, prefix, fuzzy, and range queries are to be automatically lower-cased or not (since they are not analyzed). Default it true.

Comment: +! Thank you, that is definitely the problem! I also realized that my original testing examples of the ones that started with R were actually lower-case in the index which is why they were coming back. I've updated the original question to correct the test data.

Answer (score -2):

@paulirwin @searchtechbot 
When you index this field use edgeGram filter with min :1 , max :10 and do not use prefix query just match keyword. What is going on with this is that you are indexing each part of word like: "1" "12" "123" "123-" "123-4" etc.... So just match it will find any part of your word if it is from beggining of your word.